# Ошибка взаимодействия в кнопках Дискорда

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Сделал кнопки в своём боте. При нажатии показывается **Ошибка взаимодействия.** Код:

```
async def knopka(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        embed = discord.Embed(title = '**Test**', timestamp = ctx.message.created_at),
        components = [
            Button(style = ButtonStyle.green, label = 'Да'),
            Button(style = ButtonStyle.red, label = 'Нет')
        ])
    responce = await client.wait_for('button_click', check = lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
    if responce.channel == ctx.channel:
        if responce.component.label == 'Да':
            await responce.respond(content = 'Недоступно.')
    else:
        await responce.respond(content = 'Ты нажал на Нет?')
```

Comment: Во-первых: что за библиотеку вы используете для интерактивных кнопок

Во-вторых: В коде, скорее всего, есть ошибка

Comment: библиотека DiscordComponents, если есть ошибка, то какая? лично я много рез перепроверил и ничего не нашёл

Comment: У меня ваш код работает при использовании DiscordComponents(self.bot), вы загружаете это где-нибудь? https://devkiki7000.gitbook.io/discord-components/guide/getting-started

Comment: Если у вас нигде не стоит DiscordComponents(self.bot), то вставьте после объявления функции.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте:

```
await responce.edit_origin()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]